# Find products related to patents

Tags: patent-applications, product

Apologies in advance if this is not the right place to ask the question. I am new to the forum.

I have a dataset of patent numbers and patent titles. I would like to link the patents to the products using them if any. I tried to find a solution via web scraping google patents and google shopping without success. I am wondering if there exist a database (even to be purchased) that links patents to the products using them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no database I'm aware of that links patents to products. Some companies list patents for specific products but this isn't, in my experience, common. I would guess that for the vast majority of patents there are no existing commercial products at all.